# After migrating my app to ASP.NET Core 3.0, the previously valid Index URL returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing, razor-pages

An app started in ASP.NET Core 2.0 (I think), then migrated to 2.1, then to 2.2, now I'm trying and failing to migrate it to 3.0...

I read and tried to apply instructions in the [official migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), according to which I was supposed to (among others) replace `services.AddMvc()` with `services.AddRazorPages()` and `app.UseMvc()` with `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {endpoints.MapRazorPages();})` if I was using Razor Pages. Since as far as I'm aware I was always using Razor Pages and never full-blown MVC, this is what I did.

Now previously working URLs return HTTP 404 instead of any content...

For instance, the `/` or `/Index` route does this, even though in the project directory there is a `Pages/Index.cshtml` file as well as a `Pages/Index.cshtml.cs` file. (Although oddly: maybe it is only the Index url that is failing - I just tried pointing my browser to `/Error` and it worked!)

`Pages/Index.cshtml.cs` content (unchanged from the working version):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Mon.Battle;

namespace mon.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IndexModel(IBattleManager battleManager)
        {
            // I hope I don't have to lock this dict here, I'm only reading
            configurationSerialized = battleManager.configurationSerialized;
        }

        public ConfigurationSerializedFormat configurationSerialized;

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

`Pages/Index.cshtml` also contains some content, but it is too long and too messy to post it here as a whole... But it should definitely return something and it **was** returning something before migrating to 3.0.

Page directives from the top of `Index.cshtml` are short enough however:

```
@* TODO: The site becomes ugly :( Should I start using Bootstrap, instead of trying to handcraft CSS? *@
@* Hey... I actually start to like how the site looks :) *@

@page

@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject JavaScriptEncoder jsencoder
@inject IConfiguration conf
@using static System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
@model IndexModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

These, unfortunately, had to change a bit from the pre-migration version: namely since 3.0 removed Newtonsoft.JSON, I had to replace it with `System.Text.Json`.

My current `Startup.cs` (I thought I applied instructions from the aforementioned docs precisely):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using mon.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Mon.Chat;
using Mon.MatchMaker;
using Mon.Battle;
using Mon.Player;

namespace mon
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddSingleton<IBattleManager, BattleManager>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
                endpoints.MapHub<MatchMakerHub>("/mmrhub");
                endpoints.MapHub<BattleHub>("/battlehub");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Previous `Startup.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using mon.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Mon.Chat;
using Mon.MatchMaker;
using Mon.Battle;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Mon.Player;

namespace mon
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services
                .AddSignalR()
                .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
                {
                    options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                });

            services.AddSingleton<IBattleManager, BattleManager>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
                routes.MapHub<MatchMakerHub>("/mmrhub");
                routes.MapHub<BattleHub>("/battlehub");
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What did I miss? Why does `/Index` return HTTP 404?

If you ask for any more info I'll provide.

Comment: `Index.chstml` might be too long to post, but could you post the page directives at the top without the actual content?

Comment: @JonathonChase Done.

Comment: Can you make sure that the `BuildAction` on index.cshtml is set to Content? (Right click, select properties)

Comment: @JonathonChase Was set to None. I set it to Content and finally it seems to be working! Don't know what happened, but Thank You!

Comment: With core, you can check the .csproj file and remove content directives on your razor pages safely- they are included with the build by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I had the issue with my .csproj file. Make sure your file(s) are not listed like:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Remove="Views\Extractor\Insert.cshtml" />
   <Content Remove="Views\_ViewImports.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This might happen when we copy paste the file/ change the build action etc.

Comment: Yep, I had `<ItemGroup><Content Remove="Pages\Index.cshtml" /></ItemGroup>`. Not sure what happened. But removing this seems to have resolved the issue. Thank you!